# Generate a random number between 1 and 999

Tags: php

How can i generate a random number in the range from 1 to 999 in php?

i've tried this, but i think this is not the right way

```
$characters = '0123456789';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $uniqueCode .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PHP** has a native function for this purpose which is [`rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

```php
echo rand(1, 999);
```

> Note: `rand()` works exactly as `mt_rand()` since PHP 7.1

In **PHP 7** you can use [`random_int()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) which is considered *"cryptographically secure"*:

```php
echo random_int(1, 999);
```

Answer (score 2):

just try mt_rand()

**mt_rand(min,max);**

```
 echo(mt_rand(1,999));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 8.2, there is an updated and preferred method of doing this. PHP 8.2 comes with a Randomizer class, which provides a more performant and secure way of generating random numbers (alongside many more cool features, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.random-randomizer.php)

So to generate a number between 1 and 999:

```
$randomizer = new Random\Randomizer();
$randomNumber = $randomizer->getInt(1,999);
```